# How do I store pictures on SD card by default?

Tags: sd-card, htc-sense, photos, ram

How do I move the photos I have in my gallery to my SD card? Someone told me to download an app that allows you to do this, but it didn't.

Also, is it possible to save them to the SD card by default, rather than the internal memory? Someone told me to open the camera and select settings, but there was no option to change it. I think my phone is an HTC wildfire. It's the smallest white HTC on the market and it has 'with HTC sense' on the back.

Comment: How do you know your photos aren't currently on the SD card?  I have a different phone but they're stored at `/sdcard/DCIM/` by default.

Comment: If your phone is an HTC the pics will be on the SD card by default.

Comment: It defo isn't on my memory card because my internal storage is low and all I have are pictires

Comment: Connect your phone to computer with USB cable, and select USB Drive from the notification. Then browse your SD card and search in DCIM folder, all your pictures should be there. If they are, then you are low on memory due to some installed apps.

Comment: @Matthew_Read In phones with larger amounts of internal memory, internal memory is rigged into multiple dynamic partitions.  One of these partitions actually gets mounted to /sdcard.  An actual physical SD card gets mounted to /storage/extSdCard and linked to /mnt/extSdCard.

Answer (score 2):

I have (or rather had, until a few minutes ago) a Desire C, with SD card, but photos storing on internal Memory. Unfortunatly, the previous suggestion is no option in Desire C, as there is no "storage" option in the camera app. The phone should, but does apparantly not always, default to storing pictures on the SD card.

What I did to try and solve this problem, I connected the phone to my PC as USB storage. (This connection mode is important, otherwise you cannot do the following.) 
My pictures where in the \DCIM\100Media folder on the internal storage.
I did the following

1. Copy the 100Media folder on the internal storage.
2. Paste it into the dcim folder on the SD card (in my case there was a dcim folder, if not I'd suggest you can just create it. I haven't tried that).
3. Remove the 100Media folder from the internal storage (and keep it on the desktop, just in case). At this point is no 100Media folder on the internal storage, but there is one on the SD card.
4. Unplug the phone from the PC, as camera does not work when connected to PC in USB storage mode. Try to make a picture. Actually the phone asked me: Do you want  to switch to SD? Happy to oblige.... It did apparently not create a new 100Media folder in the internal storage, exactly as I had hoped it wouldn't.

After making some test pictures, I checked by connecting to PC again as USB storage, and voilà, the pictures where on the SD card now.

Looking back, I may have had a question on storage when I first inserted the SD card, but I do not remember. I might have, since I got this queston now. If I did I must have answered it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

First confirm that your photos and videos aren't in your SD Card. To do that Unmount and Remove your SD Card from the Phone and try to use the Camera and see your previous photos.

If they are still coming up then the photos are stored in your phone internal memory.
If the photos are not coming and shows any warning message something like "Please Insert SD Card" then all your photos and videos are stored in SD Card.

I don't think so that the Photos and Videos are stored in internal memory as it is for **System Data** not for **User Data**

There might be a different folder where it stores the pictures on your SD Card.

Comment: Of course internal memory gets used for user data, at least in phones with sufficient amounts of it.  They don't shove multiple gigs of flash in there just for apps.  In such phones (e.g. my Galaxy S3.  The HTC Desire C and One V are the same, I believe, and the next units up the One line have no SD slot), you've got a partition on internal memory mounted to /sdcard and the actual SD card at /storage/extSdCard.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HTC Desire and in my case non of the other answers worked. But I solved it in his way.

Do not go into the camera app settings. Go into the general phone settings. The path is then...

Settings/Storage

Here I was able to define the default writing media from internal to SDcard. This includes also the camera app. Now my pictures can be saved either on the internal or the SD by default. You should also notice that the amount of pictures or the rest space changes.

In the HTC WildFire I had before this was done in the camera apps under settings. The thing with the move the folder and to the SDcard did not work. The phone just created the same folder again.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HTC 10 running Oreo and on that you can change the picture folder to the SD card using the options in the camera app itself.  Pull down the two bars at the top then scroll to the far left and you will find 'settings', scroll down (it isn't obvious that there are further settings below the four shown on screen), simply change the setting for 'Storage' to 'Removable Storage'.

Easy when you finally fathom it out!

Comment: That's a great answer, but probably not useful to the original questioner. The question is nearly 7 years old and about Android 2.1. I upvoted for keeping the answers relevant today.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description, I believe your phone is the [Desire C](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_c-4759.php).  To set it to send pics to the actual SD card rather than the pseudo-SD card in internal memory, you'd open the camera app, hit the menu and there should be a "storage" option you can set to "phone" or "storage card".

Answer (score 0):

Connect the phone to your PC and choose as connection "Disk Drive". Selecting this connection mode is mandatory, otherwise you will not be able to implement the steps below. Also remember that, by default, your pictures are located in the `\DCIM\100Media` folder on the internal storage.

To move your photos and define a new storage location (i.e. the SD card) proceed as follows:

1. Copy/Paste the `100Media` folder on the internal storage into the DCIM folder on the SD card (if no `DCIM` folder exists you can just create it).
2. Delete the `100Media` folder from the internal storage. Note that at this point there is no more `100Media` folder on the internal storage, but there is one on the SD card.
3. Unplug the phone from your PC. Note that the camera does not work when the phone is connected to PC in USB storage mode.
4. Open the camera application and try to take a picture. The dialog box **"Define storage location"** pops up with the following question: **"Do you want switch to the memory card?"** Select **Ok**.
5. Then, the following message appears: **"Press the screen to activate the camera"**.
6. Finally, the camera is on and you can take some pictures for a test.
7. After making some pictures, reconnect the phone to your PC and check that the test pictures are stored on the SD card.

Have fun!